# Create maps for users

Tags: google-maps, web, geolocation, maps, frontend

I wonder which is the best way to be able to create maps to be edited by users. For example a social network that the user have access to a map and he can add the path that makes cycling home. I wonder how this development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maybe Embed map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

> A map built for you
>
> Every visitor to your site sees a Google Map tailored just for them.
>   If they're signed in with their Google account, their saved places,
>   home and work locations, and more are built right into the map they
>   see. This also means that interactions with the map, such as starring
>   a location, are saved for easy viewing in Google Maps for desktop or
>   mobile.